# Inserting into many to many database behind code?

Tags: database, t-sql

I have 4 tables

```
order
item
customer
order_items
```

In `order_items` I have `item_id` & `order_id` as many to many relationship. Can anyone explain how to do right insert statement?

What I think...When button add_order is clicked, I think that I should get `item_id` from database and insert 'order_id' and `item_id` into table `order_items`. Or is it done this automaticly, when i insert new `order` into database? I need a bit of a walktrough if anyone can spare few minutes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not done automatically. You need to use a stored procedure or a trigger to do this in *one shot*. Depending on any attribute constraints, it will have to be done in a certain order. In your case, you would need to insert into `order`, then `order_items`.